# I can't get a menu dropdown fade effect to work. (Beginner)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am relatively new to coding websites and I am currently creating an online portfolio for my self, however I am stuck with a dropdown menu fade effect which I can't seem to fix in either Jquery or CSS even tho I have tried different tutorials. (Note that I am a beginner)

So my question to you guys is, what do I need to add for a fade in and out to work properly on my submenu to **"Portfolio"**?

**HTML**

```
<nav id="navbar">
    <div id="navbarcontent">
        <ul>
            <a href="index.html">
                <li class="hem">
                    <p>Hem<p>
                </li>
            </a>

            <a href="#">
                <li>
                    Portfolio
                    <ul>

                        <a href="illustrator.html">
                            <li>
                                Illustrator
                            </li>
                        </a>

                        <a href="photoshop.html">
                            <li>
                                Photoshop
                            </li>
                        </a>
                        <a href="illustrator.html">
                            <li>
                                InDesign
                            </li>
                        </a>
                    </ul>   

                </li>

            </a>
```

**CSS**

```
#navbar #navbarcontent ul {
    float:left;
    margin: 0px 0px 4px -32px;
    width:600px;
    padding-top:29px;
}
#navbar #navbarcontent ul li {
    float:left;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
#navbar #navbarcontent ul a {
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#navbar #navbarcontent ul ul {
    display:none;
}
#navbar #navbarcontent ul li.active {
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#navbar #navbarcontent ul li.active:hover {
    background-color:#43b1ff;
}
#navbar #navbarcontent ul li.active > ul {
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    top:32px;
    left:0px;
    margin-left:0px;
    width:100%;
    padding-top:0px;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
   $("#navbar ul li").hover(function() {
            $(this).addClass("active");
        }, function() {
            $(this).removeClass("active");
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried, http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/? For a css only approach, http://astronautweb.co/snippet/css3-fade-in-drop-down-menu/. Last thing, you can only have `li` inside of a `ul`, flip the a with the `li`.

Comment: I've never seen mixed tags inside a list `<ul>`. Isn't it broking it ? I mean, you have `<ul><a><li>`, I would expect `<ul><li><a>`

Comment: I did that because the whole LI needs to work as a link, not just the A tag

Comment: Don't worry, the `li` can be invisible for the user.

Comment: Here is a working example to get started, http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/y5VSb/. Here is a jQuery approach, http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/y5VSb/2/.

Comment: @Macksen To make the whole `</li>` an anchor you just need to resize your anchor to take up 100% of the space the parent element does. Your HTML is effectively malformed at this stage so should be reformatted to `<li><a>Text</a></li>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will give you the basics for both ways.

First way is with css,

```
ul#mainNav > li {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 70px;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
}

ul#mainNav > li:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.subNav {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

ul#mainNav li:hover .subNav {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

This will allow the subNav to fade in with `opacity`. (not the best way with fading on subNavs) ([JSFIDDLE CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/y5VSb/3/))

Here is the jQuery approach,

```
$('ul#mainNav li').on('click', function() {
    $(this).find('.subNav').fadeToggle(1000);
});
```

(This one is clean and simple and here is the [JSFIDDLE jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/y5VSb/2/))

(jQuery hover state)

```
$('ul#mainNav li').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).find('.subNav').fadeIn(1000);
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).find('.subNav').fadeOut(1000);
});
```

([JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/y5VSb/4/))

Comment: Hmm, but that one covers a click function, I am aiming for hovering without the need to click first, might there be some similar solution for that?

Comment: Yeah you can go ether way with that, let me find you a resource.

Comment: Finally got it to work, now it's just the styling bit, thank you very much again and marked!

Comment: You are very welcome, best of luck in your design. If you have a critical question then feel free to email me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of from `display:hidden` to `display:block`, go from `opacity:0` to `opacity:1`. Also, add a transition on the ul with `transition:opacity 0.5s`. You can adjust the time to change the duration. Keep in mind that you will need some browser prefixes for support, or you can use this library: http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/.

Comment: That would work, but CSS tends to be faster and cleaner. I like to use CSS whenever possible. Technically, animations can be considered styles.

Comment: Ok, personnaly I prefer to get rid of "some browser prefixes for support" and add only one line of code for an easier sustainability.